# An invalid implementation mymodule_form_alter was added by hook_module_implements_alter

Tags: 8, hooks, forms

I am trying to have my module alter `menu_ui` functions. Changing my module's weight didnt help and I read that `hook_module_implements_alter` is the way to go. So, as described [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/8.2.x) I am appending my module to the end of the implementations:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_module_implements_alter.
 */
function mymodule_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ('form_alter' == $hook) {
    $group = $implementations['mecca_hierarchy_access'];
    unset($implementations['mecca_hierarchy_access']);
    $implementations['mecca_hierarchy_access'] = $group;
  }
}
```

But this just throws:

> Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "An invalid implementation
>   mymodule_form_alter was added by hook_module_implements_alter()" at
>   /path/to/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleHandler.php line 591

My form alter looks like this:

```
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // commented code
}
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception is raised from the following code. (See [`ModuleHandler::buildImplementationInfo()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21ModuleHandler.php/function/ModuleHandler%3A%3AbuildImplementationInfo/8.2.x).)

```php
// If a new implementation was added, verify that the function exists.
if (!function_exists($module . '_' . $hook)) {
  throw new \RuntimeException("An invalid implementation {$module}_{$hook} was added by hook_module_implements_alter()");
}
```

In your case, it simply happens because there isn't any `mecca_hierarchy_access_form_alter()` function.

Since you want Drupal to invoke the `hook_form_alter()` implementation of your module after the other `hook_form_alter()` implementations, and since *mymodule* seems to be your module's machine name, this is the code you want to use.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_module_implements_alter().
 */
function mymodule_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'form_alter' && isset($implementations['mymodule'])) {
    $group = $implementations['mymodule'];
    unset($implementations['mymodule']);
    $implementations['mymodule'] = $group;
  }
}
```

Always verify the implementation of your module hasn't been already removed from another module, or your hook implementation would actually set `$implementations['mymodule']` to `NULL`.